# magento how to add tabs in product details page using attributes

Tags: attributes, magento-1.6

I am using easy tabs now before it was customized by other person. Now if i add attributes and add it shows me as additional info and i want to show specifications as different tab in product details page.

I have 5 tabs, Product Description, Additional Information,Deals, Reviews and Returns so here Information,Deals, Reviews and Returns this all come from static block which is customized and now i want to add Specification tab i added but its showing me under additional information as i want to show as different tab.